# usean if statement inside of ng-click directive

Tags: angularjs

I would have a question concerning ng-if in ng-click. Currently I have the following:

```
ng-click="vm.setScheduleIntervalContainerType('SERVICE_ADDED')"
```

and I will have the behavior like this:

```
ng-click="vm.setScheduleIntervalContainerType(ng-if="vm.schedulepresenceonly == true"? 'SERVICE_ADDED' : 'SERVICE')"
```

Is there any possibility to achive it like this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of ng-if, you can do this way:

```
ng-click="vm.setScheduleIntervalContainerType(vm.schedulepresenceonly == true? 'SERVICE_ADDED' : 'SERVICE')"
```

**Instead of writing logic at view level, move your condition to `vm.setScheduleIntervalContainerType()`**